# Piezo buzzer as analog sensor for ESP8266 Huzzah breakout

Tags: circuit-design, protection, esp8266, piezo

I'm using Adafruit's Huzzah ESP8266 breakout board ([overview](http://url=https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-huzzah-esp8266-breakout/overview) & [pinouts](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-huzzah-esp8266-breakout/pinouts)), and I'd like to take input from a Radioshack piezo on the analog input pin without frying it ([Piezo datasheet](http://datasheet.octopart.com/273-073-RadioShack-datasheet-11126632.pdf), for reference).

I've found a few people with a similar setup using an Arduino, and it seems like at a minimum I'd need something like a zener diode and a 1 MΩ resistor, like in the basic circuit from [this PDF](http://www.eng.utah.edu/%7Ecs5789/handouts/piezo.pdf) (page 12). The [analog pin on the Huzzah](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-huzzah-esp8266-breakout/pinouts#analog-pins) has a 1 V max. voltage, so my sense is that I've got to make some adjustments to divide down the voltage further, and maybe include a capacitor.

Any advice on including and calculating the proper values for components is appreciated.

The end goal is to take input from the piezo and use it to set hue + brightness of an RGB LED, similar to the [Adafruit LED ampli-tie project](https://learn.adafruit.com/led-ampli-tie/overview), but obviously with just a single LED. I can provide more details on that if it's relevant to getting up and running with the piezo input.

Comment: Be careful to distinguish between a piezo buzzer (which makes a continuous noise as long as you apply power to it) and a piezo sensor or element, which it the bare piezo element - it will make a "click" when you apply and remove DC power.  The buzzer won't work as a sensor.

Answer (score 1):

The 1MOhms resistor will "load" the piezo element and reducing the level of the induced voltage during normal usage. However, a sudden force applied to the element may cause a voltage spike which would kill the analog input, so you should add a series resistor of a few hundred ohms between the analog input and the piezo element.

Edit: the PDF you linked uses a Zener diode to clip the voltage, however the value it chose is a 5V Zener which is for Arduino analog inputs. You should choose a Zener with around a 1.2V breakdown voltage.